# LIST COUNT OF BETWEEN VALUES

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

i WANT TO LIST A COUNT OF 'BETWEEN' VALUES.  I CAN ONLY DO ONE RANGE AT THE MOMENT.

```
SELECT COUNT(WLU.BARCODE) "NO_BARCODES BETWEEN 3001-3002"
FROM WMSLOADUNIT WLU
WHERE WLU.BARCODE BETWEEN '3001000000' AND '3002000000';
```

I WAN TO LIST COUNT FOR BETWEEN '3002000000' AND '3003000000', BETWEEN '3003000000' AND '3004000000' AND SO ON.  CAN YOU HELP??

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING?

Comment: Sorry not intentional lol.  Can you help sevenseacat?

Comment: It's okay, I resolved it myself:

Answer (score 0):

I used CASE statement and used SUM to count the number of instances within each statement:

```
select  
 sum(case when wlu.barcode between '3001000000' and '3002000000' then 1 else 0 end)"BARCODES 3001-3002"
,sum(case when wlu.barcode between '3002000000' and '3003000000' then 1 else 0 end)"BARCODES 3002-3003"
,sum(case when wlu.barcode between '3003000000' and '3004000000' then 1 else 0 end)"BARCODES 3003-3004"
,sum(case when wlu.barcode between '3004000000' and '3005000000' then 1 else 0 end)"BARCODES 3004-3005"
,sum(case when wlu.barcode between '3005000000' and '3006000000' then 1 else 0 end)"BARCODES 3005-3006"
,sum(case when wlu.barcode between '3006000000' and '3007000000' then 1 else 0 end)"BARCODES 3006-3007"
,sum(case when wlu.barcode between '3007000000' and '3008000000' then 1 else 0 end)"BARCODES 3007-3008"
from wmsloadunit wlu
;
```

[RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hWED.png)